# Вопрос len() - 1 и Бинарный поиск

Tags: python, бинарный-поиск

Увидел в книге реализацию бинарного поиска на Python 2.7 и не могу понять почему '`high = len(list) - 1`' а не `len(list)`'. Зачем вычитать единицу ?
'''

```
def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(list) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = int((low + high)/2)
        guess = list[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None
```

'''

Comment: потому, что индекс последнего элемента это именно `len(list) - 1' а не len(list)'`

Comment: А точно это же индексы а не сами элементы, спасибо огромное)